# How to make gdb mode send proper filename to gdbserver? Running gdb from pure terminal works

Tags: debugging, tramp, gdb

I am trying to debug an application on a remote environment. Ofcourse running Tramp over gdb works as in https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Remote-processes.html, but you miss out on source code linking. The frame/stacktrace buffer for example... now you can't click on a frame and go to source code on host machine.

[Host] (Source code) -> compiled binary -> scp binary to remote -> Debug On Remote.

So I tried making gdbserver work. Firstly I made both versions of gdb/gdbserver on both host and remote machine same. 8.3 latest. Now running from terminal:

In Terminal Remote:

```
$ cd /path/to/folder/
$ gdbserver --multi :44421
```

`gdbserver` starts listening. Also tried entire exercise with `gdbserver --no-shell-on-startup --multi :44421` but it results in same thing.

In Host machine TERMINAL:

```
$ gdb /file/to/executable
gdb> target extended-remote <remote>:44421
gdb> set remote exec-file ./executable
gdb> set args -c config.xml
gdb> r
```

^This works as expected. Or atleast it starts and i am able to get debug output.

BUT In emacs GBD mode it doesn't work:
In HOST machine. EMACS:

```
M-x gdb RET gdb -i=mi /file/to/executable
gdb> target extended-remote <remote>:44421
gdb> set remote exec-file ./executable
gdb> set args -c config.xml
gdb> r
```

^This doesn't work. I get output:
In Remote Machine:

```
$ gdbserver...
...
/bin/sh: /path/to/executable/folder/executable: No such file or directory
...
```

How do I solve this?

- Emacs: 26.3
- GDB: 8.3
- Both machines are centos 7.
- Using spacemacs develop branch as emacs frontend.

Since I do frequently copy executable from host to remote, I do want gdbserver to simply run forever, hence the `--multi <port>` use case. And I can do `k` from gdb when i need to copy the binary over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this work by passing argument when launching gdb.

```
M-x gdb RET gdb -i=mi -ex "target extended-remote <remote>:44421" -ex "set remote exec-file ./executable" --args "-c config.xml"
```

Then in gdb launched i also had to set `set non-stop off`.

I ran `gdbserver` as `gdbserver --multi :44421` in the folder on remote where executable was.

It worked. But the emacs bug exists though.